# Does Mahabharata say Shiva Devotees are unaffected by planetary effects?

Tags: astrology, mahabharata, shaivism, planets

I've heard that the Mahabharata has a verse where it is said those devoted to Hara need not worry about planetary effects in their lives. Is this true ?

Comment: It's impossible to escape the effect of Grahas as long as you have a body, even if you're enlightened. At best, you can stop caring about the body and mind and what happens to them, after enlightenment. That's probably what is being referenced.